# multiply 2 value from each array of objects then add the multiplied numbers to get a total number in Reactjs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am building an eCommerce app where I want to get the total price of users ordered items. I've an array called 'orders' where I have all the ordered items. each items has 2 key calles payablePrice & purchasedQty. I want to multiply this 2 keys then i want to add the multiplied number to get the total.
Plz let me know if theres a better way to get the total,

Here is my array of objects:

[image: orderarray]

This is what i tried:

```
      {user.orders.map((order, i) => (
    <tr key={i}>
      <td> {order._id} </td>
      <td> {userName} </td>
      <td>
        {order.items.map((item) => item.payablePrice * item.purchasedQty)}
      </td>
      <td>status</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

which is not working.Plz help me get the total price of each order

The result i'm getting:
[image]

Comment: The error? could you provide it exactly?

Comment: Sorry, actually when i use .reduce((acc,cur)=> acc+cur) after .map then i get this error

Comment: So update your question :)

Answer (score 1):

So, i just had to use .reduce after .map() in the correct way this code solved my problem

```
 {user.orders.map((order, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td> {order._id} </td>
          <td> {userName} </td>
          <td>
            {order.items
              .map((item) => item.payablePrice * item.purchasedQty)
              .reduce((acc, current) => {
               return acc + current;
              }, 0)}
          </td>
          <td>status</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
```